# MongoDB compass keeeps initializing after installing

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

After downloading  and installing MongoDB compass to the PC it keeps initializing as shown in the image. Is it a common issue, or should I do any changes?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIgF5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some version of `MongoDB compass` has this problem. I had this problem before. so one of the following jobs should fix your problem.

- try to uninstall and then reinstall MongoDB compass.
- Download and install the latest stable version of the application.
- try to install the beta version. (ex. the latest beta version is 1.23.0)